# Creating a new column using loop in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables (pogba_divs & salah_divs) which have dividend pay outs for a specific player. I'm looking to build out something that allows me to compare these players' cumulative dividend returns over a specified period of time.

However, when I build my comparative charts, they look off:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeapG.jpg

```
######
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(pogba_divs.Date, pogba_divs.Dividends, label='Pogba', color='blue')
ax.plot(salah_divs.Date, salah_divs.Dividends, label='Salah', color = 'red')
legend =  ax.legend(loc='center right', fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Dividends')
plt.title('Comparison of the different prices')
plt.savefig('pogbasalah.png')
```

What I think it should look like (based on the underlying data) is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuyqU.jpg

I think the reason the chart looks odd is because of the fact that the two datasets have differing Date values? (i.e., pogba_divs.Date and salah_divs.Date don't contain the same values. The values in these columns reflect only the specific days that the two different players received dividends, with their being only occasional overlap.)

Would the best solution be to build a loop that creates a new Date column in both datasets, that contains every date within the period? So that when I try to plot them on the same chart, they both have the same Date values? (i.e. pogba_divs.Date and salah_divs.Date both contain the exact same values.)

Would love to hear what you guys think.

Comment: Yes, I do think that the dates are your problem. Fill missing values, merge both dataset to be sure that the indexes match and re-plot.

Comment: How could I go about filling the missing values?

Comment: I don't work with time series. Plus, it really depends on how they are missing. Check this link it's not specifically for Dates but you'll understand some techniques; https://towardsdatascience.com/data-cleaning-with-python-and-pandas-detecting-missing-values-3e9c6ebcf78b